# Signing Properties: Fx Build Configuration

Tags: java, javafx-2, keystore, jar-signing

In `Eclipse EE 3.7`, I've installed the `JavaFX SDK` and created a `JavaFX Project`. When I open the `build.fxbuild` file and select the `Build Properties` tab, there's a section titled `Signing Properties`. And it asks for the following information,

- Keystore
- Store-Password
- Alias
- Key-Password

For the `Keystore` field, it provides options for browsing the filesystem and workspace, but I don't know where to locate the keystore. Can anybody help me figure out how to do information signing via an Fx Build Configuration file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For many applications (for example a standalone application), code signing is simply not required - it can introduce complications and can degrade performance and user experience.  Code signing is only required for WebStart and Browser Embedded applications which require resources [outside of the Java sandbox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html).  If you are certain you actually need to sign your application, then continue reading.

Here are the steps to [create your own keystore for signing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/step3.html) using the java [keytool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html).  For test purposes you can generate your own self signed certificates.  For a real application deployed to the general public which minimizes security warnings, it is best to [purchase a code signing certificate](https://www.thawte.com/code-signing/content-signing-certificates/sun-java/index.html).

An example commmand line for creating a keystore to be used for code signing is:

```
keytool -genkey -alias signFiles -keystore examplestore
```

You will be prompted to enter passwords for the key and keystore.

The [JavaFX deployment packaging documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/packaging.htm#BABJGFBH) has information on how to sign applications via the standard JavaFX SDK.  You could just follow that description and sign your jars using, for instance, the JavaFX ant tasks.

However, it would seem that Eclipse has some inbuilt functionality for doing the signing.  If you want to take advantage of that, follow the instructions above to create your keystore.  After you have an appropriate keystore, enter the values used in creating the keystore into the appropriate fields for the Eclipse IDE to perform the signing.

Matching the fields up with the example command line for keystore generation I provided earlier.

```
Keystore - file location of the keystore containing your signing key: examplestore
Store-Password - password you assigned to access the keystore
Alias - friendly name to refer to the key: signFiles
Key-Password - password you assigned to access the key in the keystore
```

---

Although there is a default keystore provided in the Java JDK installation directory, this is not usually the same keystore which would be associated with your own signing keys and certificate.  The keystore provided with the JDK is primarily used to store certificates for certificate authorities used in validating SSL connections.  As the java keystores produced by a given jdk vendor follow one generic format, you could also use it for storing signing keys and certificates.  However, I would not advise this and would instead advise creating and using your own keystore.  Generally you want to keep the keystore containing your code signing keys separate from other information, backed up and very secure.

Comment: just wondering - doesn't OS X Gatekeeper have default security settings prohibiting running any unsigned applications? I was under the impression that this becomes not only limited to WebStart and browser embedded applications then (for latest Mac OS)

Comment: Yes mac apps need to signed for click to run, otherwise you must ctrl-click them to run.  Signing requires you buy a $99 subscription for an apple developer id which will grant you a signing cert that you can use with the apple `codesign` tool to sign the app.  This signing is a separate process from that which I described in my answer and not specific to java code.  See https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/java_applications_and_gatekeeper and https://developer.apple.com/resources/developer-id/